# What it is the content of Windows 10 packages' "FullName" property?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, package

When I run the PowerShell command *Get-Appxpackage *appname** I get a text string which is appears to me to be the value of the property *PackageFullName* / *FullName*. This string appears to be concatenated out of 5 properties, each separated by an underscore.

The 4th property is empty in my case and I cannot find any documentation on what these 5 properties are, so I cannot understand what that fourth property is supposed to contain.

The string appears to be built up like this:

```
 1. Name
 2. Version
 4. Architecture
 5. Unknown (ResourceID?)
 6. PublisherId
```

I have tried googling around for any details on this, I cannot find anything in Microsoft's documentation on "FullName" actually contains, but I suspect it's out there somewhere.

If I run the command

```
Get-appxpackage *ChipoServ*
```

in a PowerShell terminal, I get:

```
Name              : BungleWood.WoodChipper.Chipomatic.ChipoServ
Publisher         : CN=BungleWood Inc
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 0.1.1.0
PackageFullName   : BungleWood.WoodChipper.Chipomatic.ChipoServ_0.1.1.0_x64__hg64aj4mmgzja
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BungleWood.WoodChipper.Chipomatic.ChipoServ_0.1.1.0_x64__hg64aj4mmgzja
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : BungleWood.WoodChipper.Chipomatic.ChipoServ_hg64aj4mmgzja
PublisherId       : hg64aj4mmgzja
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
NonRemovable      : False
Dependencies      : { <deleted for SO post simplicity>}
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : Developer
Status            : Ok
```

If I run the same command in a PowerShell instance within a C# application, and collect the returned information with `Collection<PSObject> PSOutput`, the only content of `PSOutput` is `BungleWood.WoodChipper.Chipomatic.ChipoServ_0.1.1.0_x64__hg64aj4mmgzja`

## Lé Question

So what is the content of the fourth field? Is it the ResourceId? And where is the documentation on this?

Comment: I couldn't find anything authoritative in the documentation around PowerShell or the AppX Manifest files, but I do believe your hypothesis is correct. If I run `Get-AppxPackage | select PackageFullName,@{N='Comparison';E={ $_.Name,$_.Version,$_.Architecture,$_.ResourceID,$_.PublisherID -join "_" }} | Select *,@{N='Match'; E={($_.PackageFullName -eq $_.Comparison)}}` it shows that your theory holds true for every installed AppX package on my workstation.